# Get css file via HtmlAgiltyPack ( .Net core , c#) Console App

Tags: c#, .net

In my program I using HtmlAgiltyPack, I succeed to get all the site document and now I want to get this - >

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/user-style.css?1582723955">` (this included on the html site document)

This is my code:

```
      var web = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = web.Load(url);
        var hrefNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
        var hrefs = hrefNodes.Select(src => src?.Attributes["href"].Value).ToList();
```

Thanks.

Comment: You want `link` tags not `a` tags, so your code is wrong.

Comment: How I'll get links?

Comment: `//a` means "get anchor tags (a)", so you need to change it to get links.

Comment: What I need to write inside selectNodes function? As i see on internet when I want to get links I need to use href.

Comment: Anchor tags look like this `<a href="...">`. If `"//a[@href]"` finds those, how do you suppose you could maybe change your code to find `<link href="...">` tags?

Comment: "//link[@href]"?  